# How can I open a magnet link in Ubuntu?

Tags: bittorrent

I have qbittorrent installed.

When I click on a magnet link with Firefox it prompts me what program to use to open it.  I would love to use qbittorrent, but it is not listed there.  I search for it and it is not there.

I have qbittorrent installed and open, currently running.

This is frustrating as hell.  Why isn't it there?  Why can't I just open the file that I would of had downloaded an hour ago if I were on windows?  Why is such a simple thing so complicated in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Transmission and deluge handle this without problems. Probably qbittorrent is not set as a "magnet link capable" software.

Anyway, if you search for some of your key words on askubuntu you would end up with this:

[How do I assign magnet links to use qbittorrent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307901/how-do-i-assign-magnet-links-to-use-qbittorrent)

Answer (score 0):

Where are you searching for qbittorrent? Try looking in /usr/bin/ directory. I use deluge and I had to point to deluge binary in /usr/bin directory for the first time. Now it opens magnet links automatically in deluge.