# Wanting to make magnet urls open with qBittorrent in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, qbittorrent

Following the information seen here:
I cannot associate magnet urls to open with qBittorent. I get this error:

```
Failed to load info for handler 'qBittorrent.desktop'
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/499119/15811 and make sure you use the correct dir for the desktop file.

Comment: Yes I have a .desktop file for qBittorrent in my /usr/share/applications/ directory. But I still get the error.

Comment: qbittorrent.desktop is a launcher (desktop icon) correct? Don't you need to point Chrome to the actual program?

Comment: Yes the qBittorrent.desktop file is a launcher. I don't know how to point Chrome to the torrent client. I am fairly new to *nix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55214/how-to-override-the-gnome-3-ssh-handler/100736#100736

Opened terminal
typed in

```
gvfs-mime --set x-scheme-handler/magnet qbittorrent.desktop
```

Answer (score 3):

As of now, the new way of doing it is:

```
gio mime x-scheme-handler/magnet qbittorrent.desktop
```