# Can't open torrent magnet links

Tags: downloads, bittorrent

So far I could download torrents easily with qBittorent but now when I click on a magnet link, a new window opens saying "the link needs to be opened with an application. Send to:" qBitorrent is listed but the icon "open links" stays grey and I can no longer click on it so I can't download the torrent file.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can fix that?
FYI I use firefox and I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04,the problem seem to have started with the the upgrade...

Comment: You can open it directly from qBittorrent. And yes, something isn't right with Firefox. Maybe this stil works: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307901/how-do-i-assign-magnet-links-to-use-qbittorrent

Comment: Thanks but it no longer works...

Comment: How can I open a magnet link on PirateBay (for instance) directly on qBitorrent? The torrent link is not showed to be added in qBitorrent...

Comment: Mentioning that site was totally unnecessary. Now, even if the file type/app association isn't working in Firefox you can **always** right-click > Copy link location and then add it manually to the torrent client.

Comment: But also check Firefox's Preferences, General tab > Aplications to see which program is associated with "magnet".

Comment: Thanks very much and sorry for mentioning the site...